# Бесконечное выполнение PHP в Bash

Tags: php, bash

Есть скрипт на Bash, запускающий PHP скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

...

while [ 1 ]; do 

    /etc/php/bin/php "$LOADER_FILE"

done
```

При выполнении PHP скрипт начинает свой бесконечный цикл `while(true){...}` и при выходе из этого цикла, Bash запускает PHP снова.

При нажатии **Ctrl**+**C** завершается процесс Bash и в итоге оба скрипта (Bash и PHP) завершаются.
Как реализовать на PHP такое, чтобы при нажатии на **Ctrl**+**C** завершался не процесс Bash, а процесс PHP (т.е. просто происходил рестарт PHP скрипта)?
Возможно, это реализуется с помощью `readline()` (он считывает **Ctrl**+**C** и завершает скрипт), возможно это реализуется с помощью `pcntl_signal()`, точно не знаю, но где-то видел, что это возможно сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

обрабатывать сигналы можно с помощью встроенной команды `trap` (см. `$ help trap`)

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo "меня прервали"' int
trap 'trap - term; kill -- -$$' term
while :; do
  php -r '$n=1;while(true){sleep(1);echo $n;$n++;}'
done
```

- `trap 'echo "меня прервали"' int` — «ловим» сигнал *sigint* (см. `$ man 7 signal`), отправляемый процессу, например, при нажатии <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, и просто выводим строку `"меня прервали"`. при этом сигнал отправляется и дочерним процессам (т.е., *php*), что в данном случае приводит к «смерти» процесса *php* и к следующей итерации цикла, выполняемого программой *bash*
- `trap 'trap - term; kill -- -$$' term` — «ловим» сигнал *sigterm*, отправляемый процессу, например, при выполнении команды `$ kill идентификатор-процесса` (или `$ pkill имя-процесса`).

  внутри обработчика две команды:

  - `trap - term` — отменяем перехват сигнала *sigterm* (иначе перехват зацикливается при выполнении следующей команды `kill` и процесс завершается *segfault*-ом)
  - `kill -- -$$` — убиваем все процессы в группе (т.е., в том числе и выполняющийся процесс *php*).

  вообще при получении сигнала *sigterm* этот обработчик, конечно, срабатывает, но только если процесс *bash* в этот момент выполняет какую-либо **свою** команду. в нашем же случае в этот момент он выполняет не свою команду, а ожидает завершения процесса *php*, поэтому обработчик не вызывается **сразу**. сначала надо послать сигнал *sigterm* (например, командой `$ kill идентификатор-процесса`), а потом — *sigint* (нажав <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> в терминале, где выполняется скрипт).

пример вывода:

```
$ ./скрипт
123^Cменя прервали
123456789^CTerminated
```

после запуска скрипта и трёх итераций цикла *while*, выполняемого программой *php*, я нажал <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, скрипт вывел строку `"меня прервали"`, и программа *php* была перезапущена.

после этого в соседнем окне с эмулятором терминала я послал сигнал *sigterm* процессу (выполнив `$ pkill скрипт`), а затем нажал <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> в том окне эмулятора терминала, где был запущен скрипт. за это время *php* «успел досчитать» до девяти.